# ANGULAR - Service has not finished loading Observable<T> before being used by method

Tags: angular, typescript, service, rxjs, mat-table

So I got my HomeComponent which uses a MatTableDataSource `openFaultsSource$` which gets its data form an `Observable<IFault[]>` to display the Data as a table.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataProviderService.openFaults$.subscribe(faults => this.openFaultsSource$.data = faults);
    this.dataProviderService.closedFaults$.subscribe(faults => this.closedFaultsSource$.data = faults);
  }
```

```
IFault {
 deviceId: number,
 locationId: number,
 ...,
}
```

I don't need to display the ids but rather their connected name which i get from other Observables.
e.g.:

```
IDevice {
 deviceId: number,
 deviceName: string,
 ...,
}
```

So my HomeComponent.html looks like this:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="openFaultsSource$" class="mat-Table mat-elevation-z8">

              <ng-container matColumnDef="deviceName">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Gerätenummer </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{getDeviceNameById(element.deviceId) | async}} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="locationName">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Örtlichkeit </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.locationId}} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="creationDate">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Erstellungsdatum </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.creationDate}}  </td>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="componentName">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> betroffenes Bauteil </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.componentName}}</td>
                <td><button mat-button>test</button></td>
              </ng-container>

              <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" class="table-row" (click) = "openFaultDialog(row)"></tr> 

            </table>
```

in component.ts:

```
getDeviceNameById(id: number): Observable<string> {
    return this.dataProviderService.getDeviceNameById(id);
  }
```

My dataProviderService uses all other services, handles the logic and passes the data to the component.
It looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataProviderService {

  openFaults$: Observable<IFault[]>;
  closedFaults$: Observable<IFault[]>;

  constructor(private faultLogicService: FaultLogicService,
              private deviceLogicService: DeviceLogicService,
              private locationLogicService: LocationLogicService,
              private componentLogicService: ComponentLogicService,
              private deviceTypeLogicService: DeviceTypeLogicService,
              private faultTypeLogicService: FaultTypeLogicService,
              private solveTypeLogicService: SolveTypeLogicService) {
    this.openFaults$ = this.faultLogicService.openFaults$;
    this.closedFaults$ = this.faultLogicService.closedFaults$;
  }

  getComponentsByDeviceName(device: any): any {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  getDevicesByLocationInput(inputString: any): any {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }

  getDeviceNameById(id: number): Observable<string> {
    return this.deviceLogicService.getNameById(id);
  }

}
```

Now the deviceLogicService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeviceLogicService {

  deviceSubject = new BehaviorSubject<IDevice[]>([]);
  devices$ = this.deviceSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private deviceService: DeviceService) {
  EDIT 1: // this.init(); // init() is called in app.component when calling the 
                          // page for the first time 
  }

  init() {
    this.deviceService.getDevices()
    .pipe(tap(console.log))
    .subscribe(devices => {
      this.sortDevices(devices);
      this.deviceSubject.next(devices);
    });
  }

  sortDevices(devices: IDevice[]) {
    devices.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
  }

  getNameById(deviceId: number): Observable<string> {
    return this.devices$.pipe(map(devices => devices.find(device => device.id === deviceId).name));
  }
}
```

deviceService which is used by deviceLogicService to populate its BS:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeviceService {

  private accessPointUrl = 'https://localhost:44360/api/Devices/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getDevices(): Observable<IDevice[]> {
    return this.http.get<IDevice[]>(this.accessPointUrl);
  }
}
```

[THE PROBLEM]
Basically it is working and it is loading the right names to the chosen ids but the problem is that I get the error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at MapSubscriber.project (device-logic.service.ts:77)` because it is calling the method before the service is finished loading all the devices.

[QUESTION]

Is there a way to tell the method to wait till all devices have been loaded?
Is the structure of my code ok, or is it to complex?
Is there an easier way for the same outcome?

I'm fairly new to Angular and I just don't know how to get this fixed. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you please add the code that show how and where the BS is populated?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added the service the deviceLogicService uses to populate its BS.

Comment: I guess one thing I could do is to add a bool to home.comp.html which changes when devices are loaded, to tell the table not to rend?

Comment: Yep, I would add a boolean variable too!

Comment: You could show the table only if the data is fully loaded *ngIf="dataIsLoaded".
You could also use a resolver instead to load the required data before the route is rendering the html (read about resolvers). I am not sure it is good practice to load the data in an "init" of a service. Hope this helps.